# What is the correct sentence give or gives?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct?

- This give me hope in the world
- This give**s** me hope in the world

Comment: There are hundreds of websites that show how to conjugate English verbs, e.g. **[this one](http://bab.la)**. You should find one you like and bookmark it. Conjugating verbs, especially irregular ones like _to give_, is basic to your study of English.

Answer (score 3):

All regular (and many irregular) verbs in English have two forms in the present: "third person singular", which ends in *-s*, and "everything else". The correct form is the one that agrees with the subject of the verb.

All of the following are third person singular:

- Singular nouns
- Personal pronouns "he", "she", and "it"
- Demonstrative pronouns "this" and "that"
- Interrogative pronouns "who", "what", etc. (unless context implies that they're standing in for something plural)

In your sentence, "this" is the subject (and "me" is the indirect object, while "hope" is the direct object). So the correct form is "third person singular" with the *-s* on the end: **gives**.

Comment: *Who are* these people? *What are* the cars waiting for? http://www.englishlanguageguide.com/grammar/interrogative-pronoun.asp

Comment: @RonaldSole: I take it from the first sentence that your point is that interrogatives can be plural? I'll edit to mention that. In your second sentence, though, the subject is "the cars", not "what", which is still construed as singular: "What *is* it that the cars are waiting for?"

Comment: Yes! Interrogatives can be either singular or plural. My second example was an own goal.